# How to count users in table with php

Tags: php, mysql

in wordpress custom php this code works:

```
$result = count_users();
echo 'There are ', $result['total_users'], ' total users';
foreach($result['avail_roles'] as $role => $count) {
    echo $count, ' are ', $role, 's', ', ' . "<br />";
}
echo '.' . "<br />";
```

Here is an example of output by that:

There are 14 total users

1 are administrators,
3 are s2member_level1s,
 
13 are access_s2member_ccap_video, 
13 are access_s2member_ccap_saas, 
1 are access_s2member_ccap_optins, 
10 are subscribers,

So, is there a way to count all users with a role, like say: s2member_level1s, or access_s2member_ccap_saas with just one call, or do I have to do it like that, then count the foreach results, every time?

I am hoping there is a way to just count them with one pull, so it does not take a lot of resources and time for the page to load, everytime we load the page.

Thanks,
-Rich

Comment: yes, a case/when is one way, with the old 1 or 0 trick

Comment: your output, has the answer you asked for, so i'm confused as to what you want."3 are s2member_level1s" then  "is there a way to count all users with a role, like say: s2member_level1s"

Comment: it is counted in the foreach: foreach($result['avail_roles'] as $role => $count) {
    echo $count, ' are ', $role, 's', ', ' . "<br />";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping through the results and print the key of each one, you should be able to access directly the result using the key:

```
$result = count_users();
echo $result['avail_roles']['s2member_level1s'];
```

Here's more information on arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: please dont link to w3schools, its dangerously bad

Comment: Thanks for noticing me/editing my post, but can you explain to me why it's so bad? I find their interface to be a little less dry than the php documentation, easier/tutorial to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the query this way to get results instantly from database single query

```
select user_id,
    count(*) totalusers,
    sum(case when avail_roles = 'administrators' then 1 else 0 end) administratorsCount,
    sum(case when avail_roles = 's2member_level1s' then 1 else 0 end) s2member_level1sCount,
............
from userstable
group by user_id
```

So `administratorsCount` gives number of administrators etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply executing mysql query, without running a php loop . You just need to use group by with your column name that defines roles(e.g. roletype).

```
SELECT count(*), roletype FROM `user` group by roletype
```